# Multiple action when click on Disabled Button [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Let's assume I have a program that when I click a button, it performs a very important action that lasts 3 minutes. The action is to be performed only once even though the button was accidentally clicked, e.g. twice. After clicking the button, I added a lock for this button so that it cannot be clicked a second time. However, despite the lock being turned on, when I click on the blocked button, after 3 minutes the action will start a second time and I have to wait again. How to solve the problem of performing an action multiple times after clicking on a button that is blocked? Attached is a simple project as an example. For example, I added a simple variable increment action and simulated the passage of time using Thread.Sleep. When you click the button, the textbox displays the value "i" increased by 1. Additionally, the button is disabled to avoid accidentally clicking it twice. The button locks for 2 seconds. However, if within these 2 seconds I click on the button, e.g. 3 times, the action will be performed 3 times even though the button is locked.
Here is an example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Button_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int i = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(++i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            textBox1.Refresh();
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Make the `Click` event handler async and `await Task.Delay(2000);` instead of `Thread.Sleep(2000);` (which causes some re-entrancy issues)

Comment: I made a test, and it surprised me that the button clicks are being registered even so the button is disabled. This also happens if I replace `Thread.Sleep(2000);` by a long-running loop. @Jimi's suggestion together with disabling the button solves the problem and also keeps the UI responsive.

Comment: I don't mean replacing Thread.Sleep(2000); with await Task.Delay(2000);. There will be a long-running loop performing operations on the data. How to make the Click event handler async ???